# Identifying Metals at Home

Tags: discussion

I'm posting this on meta because I'm not entirely sure if this is the site for it. The sidebar suggested I that this was the place to put it, so I'm doing here. *Is this question appropriate for this stack exchange? If not, where ought this question go?* Mouse over to see the questionable question here:

> I have an item which is made of some magnetic metal. Obviously, testing if a metal is magnetic or not eliminates many alloys and metals (such as Al), but it does not let me know the grade or quality and composition of the metal. I would like to know if it is a stainless steel or a carbon steel (and if it is a mid or high carbon steel)! What tests can I run at home to determine what metal this item is?

Comment: We already have http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19946/, which I seem to recall generated some controversy at the time it was posted. Given that it has been a while, I'm not sure we should take the existence of that question as definitive.

Comment: @dmckee Interesting that the "questions which might have an answer" section did not bring this up. I am glad I asked here!

Comment: That tool is erratic. Apparently the team thinks it is not worth the effort to try to make it better (a really great job would require fault tolerant natural language processing, after all).

Comment: Wasn't identifying the chemical makeup of matter the job of analytical chemistry?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty That's the way to do it correctly, of course. Question 19946 predated the chemistry beta and I interpreted it as asking for rules of thumb and at-home sorts of tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of keeping meta clear of unanswered questions: I suspect this would not be appropriate. If you were to justify why this needs to be done in the context of a research-level physics experiment, then it might be acceptable, but in general I'd expect it to get closed if you post it on the main site.